# PyTelegrambotApi — @callback_query_handler doesn't turn to the next step of the bot

Tags: python, python-decorators, py-telegram-bot-api

I'm using `PyTelegrambotApi` to create a bot.

Requesting and receiving data appears to work; however, when I'm using the inline keyboard and create `callback_query_handler` to handle the user's choice the callback does not appear to fire.

Once the user has made a choice, the user should be asked for a price, but as it stands I have to send a message to the bot to trigger it. The bot will stay frozen until I send a random message - for example "Hey?" - and only then the bot starts the next step.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def user_answer(call):
    user[call.message.chat.id].city_id = call.data #creates dict from received data
    bot.register_next_step_handler(call.message, get_price) # <-- stuck at this point
```

The next step is:

```
def get_price(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'What's the price?')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, save_price)
```

Can somebody assist me to figure it out, please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to resolve this problem.

Instead of register the next step, I just called function and it works well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

As I remember `register_next_step_handler` uses new message that user sents and you inputed message that was already sent.

Comment: You are correct!